# featherlight.js background & close button css?

Tags: javascript, css, featherlight.js

I want to use a simple js to deactivate and activate the overflow of the html `"body"` like this:

```
$('.my_link').click(function(){
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
});

$('.featherlight_background & featherlight_close_button').click(function(){
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
});
```

But I dont finde out the css name of the "featherlight_background" and the "featherlight_close_button" - ... ".featherlight:last-of-type" and ".featherlight-close-icon" dont work ;(.

That´s the script I work with: [featherlight](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest solving it using the configuration options of Featherlight instead of adding jQuery events to its elements.

Looking at the [Configuration section of Featherlights documentation](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#configuration) it seems you can define a function to be called when the lightbox is opened or closed, see `beforeOpen`, `afterOpen`, `beforeClose` and `afterClose`.

You can either define those functions using a data attribute on the element, e.g. `data-featherlight-before-open`, by overriding the global defaults, e.g. `$.featherlight.defaults. beforeOpen`, or by adding them as a parameter to your featherlight call, e.g. `$.featherlight('#element', { beforeClose: ... });`

I've added a small example that uses the global configuration method to change the text `Lightbox is closed` into `Lightbox is open` when opening the lightbox.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').featherlight('#lightbox');
  
  $.featherlight.defaults.beforeOpen = setLightboxOpen;
  $.featherlight.defaults.afterClose = setLightboxClosed;
});

function setLightboxOpen() {
  $('#text').text('Lightbox is open');
}

function setLightboxClosed() {
  $('#text').text('Lightbox is closed');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/master/release/featherlight.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/master/release/featherlight.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Open lightbox</button>
<p id="text">Lightbox is closed</p>

<div id="lightbox" class="hidden">
  Lightbox contents
</div>
```